# Django и cron

Tags: cron, python, django

Возникла задача выполнять скрипт по расписанию. Вот начал гуглить и встал вопрос, актуально ли сейчас использовать [django-cron](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/) или же можно обойтись написанием [custom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) команды для **manage.py**.
PS
Собственно сейчас делаю для теста простой скрипт дампа базы.
Потом надо будет делать рассылку.
**UPD**
Для дампа базы использовал хорошую тулзу [Database Dump Script](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DbDumpScript).
Для работы с cron использовал custom-команды, было интересно что и как. Скажу что все предельно просто. Создается команда которая вызывается через **manage.py** *команда*.
**Преимущества:** довольно просто задать свои атрибуты команды и входные параметры команды. Может есть более четкое мнение почему так лучше , чем изгаляться через скрипты. Буду рад узнать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, подключать дополнительные приложения и писать кастомные команды для выполнения задач по крону - это слишком много лишних телодвижений.
Достаточно написать простой Python-скрипт, в нем добавить путь к Django-проекту в PYTHONPATH и указать путь в переменную окружения `'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'`. Далее по файлу работаете с Django-проектом как обычно.
Для примера кусочек из своего:

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import os  
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject/')   
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from myproject.myapp.models import SomeModel

def do_smth():  
    return SomeModels.objects.filter(smth=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    do_smth()
```

Ну и добавляем этот файл в крон.
Все.

Comment: Ещё бы не мешало написать `import django` и `django.setup()`
А то Django не поймёт что от него хотят

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим высказыванием, но бывает так что надо (хочется) чтоб прям в Django cron жил. У меня был опыт использования [django-crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab), мне понравилось! Простой как топор.