# Реализация - Cron и Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Стал вопрос использования крон-задач в проекте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это релизовать. Может есть уже какие то решения? Находил некоторые, но они уже старые и в новых версиях Django (у меня 1.10) не поддерживаються. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Каких задач, что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: @m9_psy я еще не начинал делать это, поэтому пока "не получается" нет. я просто спрашиваю совета, может кто то делал крон задачи у себя в django проекте. интересно что используют. // мне нужно запускать один метод в полночь.

Comment: тогда читайте мануал по `cron` и `crontab`, собственно, на этом все вопросы должны отпасть. Запускаете `crontab -e` - откроется текстовый редактор по-умолчанию, в котором можно добавить или изменить задачу. Каждая строка в этом файле - отдельная задача Пример для полночи: `0 0 * * * python3 /path/to/my_script.py`. Расшифровывется как каждый месяц, каждый день в 0:0 запускать такой-то скрипт.

Comment: Также в помощь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/17991/django-%d0%b8-cron?rq=1

Comment: @m9_psy спасибо. вот нашел еще решение https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на Celery, возможно это то что вам нужно.
Применение в django: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html